# Is it possible to change|renew my "Temporary IPv6 Address" - windows (preferable via Python)

Tags: python, windows, networking, ip, ipv6

Best,

The title says it all: 
**Is it possible to change|renew my "Temporary IPv6 Address" - in windows (preferable with Python)**
(via code)

I've noticed that, when I'm using my 5ghz wifi, and switch to the 2.4 ghz wifi & immediately back to the 5ghz wifi, that my Temporary IPv6 Address has been changed.

And for some specific reasons, I would like recreate this behaviour via python code. (or powershell, or cmd ( as long as python can execute the function or -windows command))

[image]

Kind regards

Comment: @Cyclonecode -i'll give it a shot

Comment: I updated my answer. The adapter needs to be configured to use DHCP. I think this can be done automatically by issuing a `netsh` command.

Comment: @Cyclonecode - in the command line, i've tryed ipconfig /release & /renew    but it only  extended the   Lease Obtained  & .Lease Expires

dates

Answer (score 0):

Under windows you should be able to use `ipconfig`:

```
import os

def refresh_ip():
  # Switch to dhcp
  system('netsh interface ip set address "Wi-Fi" dhcp');
  system('ipconfig /release6 Wi-Fi')
  system('ipconfig /renew6 Wi-Fi')
```

The above might not work so here is a solution for non dhcp adapters, note that this is for Python3:

```
import ipaddress
import os

# Set specific ipv6 unicast address of adapter "Wi-Fi"
def set_ip(ipv4):
  ipv6 = ipaddress.IPv6Address('fe80::' + ipv4).compressed;
  os.system('netsh interface ipv6 set address "Wi-Fi" ' + ipv6)

set_ip("192.168.0.1")
```

Comment: i receive this message:
No operation can be performed on Ethernet 3 while it has its media disconnected.
Adapter vEthernet (DockerNAT) is not enabled for DHCP.
No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 2 while it has its media disconnected.
Adapter Wi-Fi is not enabled for DHCP.
No operation can be performed on Bluetooth Network Connection while it has its media disconnected.

Comment: @Dieter - I updated the answer so it only targets the specific `Wi-Fi` adapter. The error message you are getting seems to point out that the adapter is using a static ip, can you change the configuration so it using dhcp instead? I added a command that should switch to dhcp for the specific adapter. Not sure this will work though.

Comment: i've added a  image on the main question, of the output  of the command line

Comment: @Dieter - I added another solution that might work. Of course this justs assigns a new ipv6 address to the specified adapter, but you should be able to tweak this to suite your needs.

Comment: @Dieter I added another solution.

Comment: i'll test it later this day,  kind regards